# Gravity Forms with Ajax - multiple ajax preloaders appearing when user clicks Next

Tags: ajax, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm using Gravity Forms integrated with Paypal and Stripe, allowing users to directly pay from the product page without the need for a checkout page.

With all the different product options, I've had to use a multi page form with quite a bit of conditional logic.

I'm wanting to use Ajax to avoid the user having to reload the page.

However, when a user clicks "Next" on the multipage form, rather than there being one preloading spinner there are between 2 and 4.

This looks a complete mess, but I have no idea how to fix it.

If anyone has any suggestions as to why there are so many of the preloaders at one time, that would be really helpful, but I suspect it has something to do with how many conditional logic fields I've used.

In a perfect world I'd be able to find a solution to get it back down to only the one preloader. However, I accept it is probably an easier solution to just remove the preloader icon altogether.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks so much. This has been driving me crazy!

Comment: Please post some code, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I realize you posted this a month ago, but I solved a similar issue with CSS:

```
.gform_ajax_spinner {
    display: none;
}

.gform_ajax_spinner:nth-child(1) {
    display: block;
}
```